# How to delete a Redis Stream?

Tags: redis

I've created a Redis stream:

```
XADD mystream * foo bar
```

And I've associated it with a consumer group:

```
XGROUP CREATE mystream mygroup $
```

Now I want to delete it, so that Redis acts as though the stream had never existed. How do I delete it?

I've tried using XTRIM:

```
XTRIM mystream MAXLEN 0
```

This successfully puts the length of the stream to zero. But it doesn't fully delete the stream, as attempts to `XREADGROUP` still succeed and do not return the typical error when this method is called without the group existing:

```
XREADGROUP GROUP mygroup myconsumer COUNT 1 STREAMS mystream >
```

Actual output:

```
(nil)
```

Expected output:

```
NOGROUP No such key 'mystream' or consumer group 'mygroup' in XREADGROUP with GROUP option
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just use the DEL command:

```
DEL mystream
```

Answer (score 5):

Pretty straightforward answer, right away from [the first search online](https://redis.io/commands/del).

Just execute:

```
DEL stream_name
```

`XTRIM` only removes the data within the stream, but does not delete the stream itself or any groups associated to it.